# Easiest way to grab "target" key from the hash shown

Tags: arrays, perl, hash-of-hashes

This is the output of Dumper for the hashref in question:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;

sub getUpgradeTaskUUIDS {
    my $derp = SF::Transaction::Update::getUpgradeTasks();
    print "Derp is:\n";
    print Dumper $derp;
    [... do stuff ...]
}
```

The following hashref is received by another function. task_readiness may have elements, it may not. I managed to grab the "target" => '_6f5c8c84-6251-11eb-8def-fd627969bf5f_52dcea68-60e9-11eb-830e-f71d7dc3a91f' in some convoluted way, but I am wondering what the cleanest, simplest way would be? I need to be able to grab target -> '' values from both task_readiness and task_upgrade as well if both have applicable elements:

```
Derp is:
$VAR1 = {
          'tasks_readiness' => [],
          'tasks_upgrade' => [
                               {
                                 'type' => 6,
                                 'hidden' => 0,
                                 'state_name' => '1',
                                 'allow_html_in_msg' => 1,
                                 'aq_id' => '0e43ed66-663e-11eb-a97b-b72c0f665ee4',
                                 'subtype_name' => '',
                                 'retry_type' => 1,
                                 'safe_to_delete' => 1,
                                 'create_time' => 1612370227,
                                 'delay_run' => 1612370299,
                                 'last_state_change' => 1612370287,
                                 'description' => 'Apply Upgrade 7.0.0-1242 to Devices',
                                 'subtype' => 14,
                                 'group_name' => 'DEVICE_UPGRADE',
                                 'name' => '',
                                 'type_name' => '6',
                                 'retries' => 0,
                                 'state' => 1,
                                 'target' => '_6f5c8c84-6251-11eb-8def-fd627969bf5f_52dcea68-60e9-11eb-830e-f71d7dc3a91f',
                                 'domain' => 'e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f',
                                 'cost' => 10,
                                 'pid' => 0,
                                 'message' => '<p><strong>Failed to update 2 devices.<br></strong></p><p><strong>Please reapply policies to your managed devices.</strong></p>',
                                 'user' => 'admin'
                               }
                             ]
        };
```

Comment: _"I managed to grab the `"target" => '_6f5c-...-a91f'` in some convoluted way"_. Please [edit] your post and include the code for the "convoluted way".

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get the value you want would probably be:

```
$derp->{tasks_upgrade}[0]{target}
```

And increment that 0 if you have other entries in the array.

**Note:** Thanks to Jim Garrison for pointing out my earlier idiocy.

Comment: Do you mean `$derp->{tasks_upgrade}->[$n]->{target}` for some value of `$n`?